# Troubleshooting Google Author

Tags: google, google-search-console, author

I have successfully implemented the neat Google Author feature on my Computer Performance website.  However, I am struggling to set it up on my fashion-era.com website.  The only difference is that the site where it does not work lacks the pure tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Instead fashion-era has

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

One more thing, the Google snippets tools indicates it should work on the fashion era pages.

Question: Could this Doctype prevent the Google Author feature working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the DOCTYPE should not affect the Google author feature. However, I would make sure your pages validate.

If you have deemed that this is not working because the author information does not appear in the search results then keep in mind that Google is still trialling this feature and states that:

> Google doesn't guarantee to show author information in Google Web
>   Search or Google News results.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986

Comment: Update: Today 1 page has the Author picture.  It will be interesting to see if the other pages also show the picture - given time.